# SSMS Problema con archivo de solución

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server (versión express), pero al momento de querer guardar mi archivo de consulta y querer cerrar el programa. Me sale siempre un cuadro de diálogo para guardar un archivo .ssmssln el cual ya tengo guardado en el escritorio. Además, aunque no haga ningun cambio en el archivo de consulta, el diálogo aparece de todas formas al querer cerrar, lo cual es realmente molesto. Lo que quiero hacer es guardar la consulta en .sql. Hasta ahora he probado reinstalando, instalando la versión developer, pero nada ha dado resultado. Adjunto captura del mensaje en cuestión. [image: Problema sql server]

Answer (score 0):

Un WPI release de Microsoft para instalar Clientes Manager SQL en 32 Bits y 64 Bits. El Wpi te Administra las Versiones encontradas y da opciones de Remover Reinstalar u Instalar Clientes Superiores u Anteriores a tu Instancia de SQLserver ademas de una serie de artilujios para el jobweb.